# Find out the table name where items gets saved - opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

When a person clicks on the add to cart button, that particular record gets stored in the database. I want to know the table name where Items are saved.

later i will add new field to this table.

My Questions are :

1.) What is the name of the database table that's responsible for the above requirement.

2. I need to `ALTER` the above table to add a column 'STATUS_OF_COLUMN'.

`ALTER TABLE <I need the table name>
ADD STATUS_OF_COLUMN String`

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Cart contents are stored as a serialized string in the `cart` field of the `customers` table. As such, it doesn't have its own table structure.

2) As per 1), there's no table to modify. You might want to look at modifying the string that's stored. You can find the related methods in `/system/library/cart.php`